# Get rid of *~ files in KDE editors

Tags: kde, editors

All the KDE based editors (Kate, KWrite, Kile, etc.) tend to produce recovery (?) files that are named like the edited file with a tilde at the end. The annoying thing is that these files are left even after I quit the editor. How can I disable this behaviour? I don't mind having these while I am editing (if they help with anything), but I don't want them after I finish.

Comment: Just a thought... you may not want to do that. Sooner or later it will hapen that you'll erase or overwrite the file unexpectedly (and that happens usually when you DON'T have the file open). At that point, these are the only ones that can save you. All the *nix editors do that for a reason - better safe than sorry. It's standard to have `-B` switch aliased in `ls` so you don't even notice them until you need to find them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Settings > Configure > Editor Component > Open/Save > Advanced, and uncheck the box next to local files under "Backup on Save".